# WordPress get single link to couple categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I have small tree of categories:

e.g.

> -main        (id: 10)
>
> --firstSub   (id: 14)
>
> --secondSub (id: 15)
>
> --thirdSub   (id: 16)

What i want is to get one link to couple of subcategories (e.g. link to ids: 14 and 16) or link to main category exclude one subcategory (id:10 -id:15). And i don't know how to solve this. `Get_the_category()` work only for single category, `get_the_terms()` doesn't work with array of categories. I search for any possible solve of this problem, and i doesn't match anything.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run a custom loop for doing that...

1. Create a page template in your theme...
   https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/
2. Right after template comments add a loop...
   https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Using_the_Loop
3. Add category parameters as desired, cat ids separated by comma and excluded categories prefixed by minus sign...
   `$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=10,-15' ); //Shows posts in category 10 not in 15`
4. Now you have right posts queried, just use post template tags ( or post template part if your theme has it ) to output the posts as desired.
   https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags#Post_tags